# Open all links not part of my website in new window with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, adsense, logical-operators

Im not sure what i have to put in the '???' to make it check if the website is my address or not. Will this also work for google adsense ads(just wondering, but not important)?

I was thinking of using a logicial operator like 'not'. So it will check if NOT my website? So then the ??? would be my website?

```
$j(!a[href=???]).click(function(){
                window.open(this.href, "target=_blank");
                return false;
            });
```

Comment: You realize that this way, you break all your links if a popup blocker is enabled? 

It's much, much better to do this directly in the HTML source, where a `target="_blank"` will work without triggering popup blockers.

Comment: @Pekka so i see using the .click() with window.open would break the links, but the method below that uses the .attr() and adds that html code in that you mentioned should not break it, correct?

Comment: the method below with adding `target="_blank"` shouldn't break it, you're right.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$j('a')
    .not('[name^="http://your.domain.com/"]')
    .attr('target', '_blank');
```

**Update**

My previous fix only works *if all URLs are absolute*, which was a bad assumption.  Try this instead:

```
$j('a[name^="http:"], a[name^="https:"]')
    .not('[name^="http://your.domain.com/"]')
    .attr('target', '_blank');
```

This new version skips all relative URLs.  If all of your in-site URLs are relative (i.e. don't start with `https?:`), you can skip the call to `.not`.

Comment: I tried this and it somewhat worked because the pages of my website are opening up in new windows, which is what i was trying to avoid. I dont know why it doesn't work either.

Comment: i tried it with the :not vs .not() and it still turned every link on my page into target=_blank links.

Comment: @Nils R - if you're still having troubles, I included a demo with the version that is less intensive on the web browser and a bit more flexible

Comment: Sorry, @NilsR.  My answer was flawed, but I've updated it now.

Comment: @Jacob can you please explain what the `^=` is doing?

Comment: @Bups: `^=` means "starts with."

Answer (score 3):

Running anything like `$( 'a' )` is going to loop through EVERY `A` element - you can only worry about it on the actual click. Also, you can just run with relative urls being your site, and absolute url's being someone else's.

```
$( document ).on( 'click', 'a', function( event ){
  var $a = $( this );
  // test for anything like `http://` or '//whatever' or 'ftp://'
  if ( /^\w+?\:?\/\//.test( $a.attr( 'href' ) ) ){
    // since this runs before the event is propagated,
    // adding it now will still work
    $a.prop( 'target', '_blank' );
  }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/danheberden/3bnk9/

Or you can use window.open:

```
$( document ).on( 'click', 'a', function( event ){
  var href = $( this ).attr( 'href' );
  // test for anything like `http://` or '//whatever' or 'ftp://'
  if ( /^\w+?\:?\/\//.test( href ) ){
    // dont follow the link here
    event.preventDefault();

    //  open the page
    window.open( href, '_blank' );
  }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/danheberden/NcKdh/

Comment: this actually seems like a great method, the only issue i can see with this is that if someone for some reason has JS turned off then all of my links are broken because i have to follow a new url pattern for anchor links for this to work.

Comment: Huh? If JS is disabled this entire approach is busted, which is why you should be adding `target="blank"` to your HTML and not the way your question asked to do it :)

Comment: Thanks, but the reason for me adding this JS is because there is one specific page that i need all urls to go to a new window(per request) and almost the whole page is dynamic, but ya i do use target="_blank" when i can.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a class to do it:

```
// Outbound Links
var outLinks = function() { $('a[@class*=out]').click( function(){ this.target = '_blank'; } ); }
$(document).ready(outLinks);
```

Then all you need do is add the "out" class to any link and it will open a new window.

Or for any link which starts with http://

```
$('a[href^="http://"]').prop("target", "_blank");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$j('a').live('click', function(){
  if(this.href.indexOf('yourwebsite.com') == -1) {
    window.open(this.href, "target=_blank");
    return false;
  }
});
```

This could also be improved with a regex so that it doesn't catch URLs like http://someothersite.com/yourwebsite.com/, but it's an edge case.